# VBA code for updating autofilters without re-applying

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

While updating a table with VBA, is there a way to refresh the autofilters without manually re-applying it? Say, I have a value in A1 that serves as the filter for Column 1 of Table 1. When I clear the content in A1, can VBA automatically clear the filter in column 1 without re-executing the code? Or if I update the value of A1, is there a way for the filter of column1 to be automatically updated as well?

I have tried

```
Sub Name()
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Name(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Name(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
     .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End With
End Sub
```

from various sources. I made sure the code is embedded in the same sheet as the filter modules, but I still seem to be doing something wrong... Any help would be appreciated!

link to sources:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4180-excel-refresh-filter-automatically.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1004207/macro-for-reapply-filter-on-excel-2016
https://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-i-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed

Comment: Look into a [`Worksheet_Change()` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).

Comment: I'll do that and get back to you. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using dependent drop down lists.  You can download a sample file at the bottom of the URL listed here.

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Also, download the sample file from here.

https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-excel-filter/

Finally, download the sample file form this link, below.

http://chandoo.org/wp/2015/08/22/filter-as-you-type-excel/

Comment: Umm that's an interesting to approach it! I actually use it for something else in the same spreadsheet, but it never occurred to me to use it this way. Thank you for your input, I will try this. :)

Comment: Please mark my answer as helpful if it did indeed help you resolve your issue.  Thanks.